# In tensorflow for images dataset, error: Can't convert object to 'str' for 'filename'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have to train a neural net model for a video dataset. I had preprocess the dataset and extracted the frames of videos in each video folder. That is how the model accepts the input.

The error reads like:

```
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: TypeError: Can't convert object to 'str' for 'filename'
         [[Node: PyFunc = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_STRING, DT_BOOL], Tout=[DT_FLOAT], token="pyfunc_5"](arg0, PyFunc/input_1)]]
         [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[300,227,227,3], [1]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Iterator)]]
```

I find this error in python/client/session.py. What is the mistake I'm doing?

Comment: can you share the code also

Comment: Where is the code that causes this error?

Comment: please review [mre]